# golang - read string argument include &

Tags: go

How do I read string argument include & in Go for example this link

> $ ./main
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX

without use double quotation (")

> $ ./main
>   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX"

main.go

```
package main

import (
        "os"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        link := os.Args[1]

        fmt.Println(link)
}
```

> $ go build main.go
>
> $ ./main
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX

output will be

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA

Comment: `&` is interpreted by your shell. You must quote or escape it.

Comment: The `&` is being interpreted by your shell, it's not even being received by your program. There is no way to do this without escaping it or enclosing the argument in quotes.

Comment: then how do program like youtube-dl can read it.

Comment: @stackdev: It's not. The list parameter on it's own isn't going to change which video you link to.

Comment: Their documentation even shows examples of escaping `&`: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: thanks @JimB , i have understood this point.

Answer (score 0):

Both @JimB and @Adrian are correct, the `&` needs to be escaped.

If you absolutely must find a workaround, you could opt to not use a command-line argument and rather read input instead to bypass need for escaping.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var input string
    fmt.Scan(&input)
    fmt.Println(input)
}
```

**input:**

`$ ./main
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX`

**output:**

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX`

Comment: $ ./main https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX
output : [4] 4403

[3]+  Stopped                 ./1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA

Comment: Ah, that is because this approach does not use command line arguments so you don't run the command the same way- you need to await the input, and then paste in the youtube link.

Comment: Run `./main` and then once the program begins, post in the link